# Are there baby changing rooms at Delhi airport?

Tags: transit, india, children, del

We are planning to travel with our new born daughter from Finland(Helsinki) to India(Coimbatore) via Delhi. She will be 2 months old during the travel date. There is 7 hours of transit at Delhi Airport.

We arrive in International terminal at T3 and our domestic flight to Coimbatore is indigo from T1D terminal. Are there any baby nursing rooms available in International arrival area (T3) or Domestic departure area (T1D) where we could spend time during the transit.

I have noticed from interactive map that nursing rooms are available in International Departure area but was not clear if they have any at International arrival area (T3) or Domestic departure area (T1D). We are looking at tips on how to mange this 7 long hours with our little one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does have baby changing and play area facilities.

source [here](https://www.flyingwithababy.com/airport-guide/) and [here](https://momaboard.com/traveltip/airport-nursing-rooms-worldwide/)

They even provide free [stroller for toddlers](http://www.hindustantimes.com/delhi-news/baby-strollers-now-available-at-indira-gandhi-international-airport/story-eN1AHVn2cndioiqlAE2n2I.html)